# download kml file throuth tag <a>,browser not handle mimeType 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml'

Tags: javascript, blob, kml

when i use a tag for downloading kml file, browser doesn't recognize right extension.
then i try mimetype https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml,
some works some doesn't.i use Chrome for the test.
any one can help? thanks...

```
let url = URL.createObjectURL(
         new Blob([string format kml data], { type: 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml' })
       )
const link = document.createElement('a')
link.style.display = 'none'
link.href = url
link.setAttribute('download', 'filename')
document.body.appendChild(link)
link.click()
document.body.removeChild(link)
URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
```

Comment: You want to download that file or display it in the browser? Why should the browser recognize any extension here? You set the extension to nothing when you do `link.setAttribute('download', 'filename')`. The browser will not look at the content of the data being downloaded. And don't revoke the blob:// URI right after the click, downloading a resource is asynchronous, by the time you revoke it, you can't know if the browser already fetched it or not.

Comment: i just need download it.and when i use  


new Blob([JSON.stringify(item.feature)], { type: 'application/json' })


it works fine,file with right extension

Comment: Once again, the browser doesn't look at the content to set the extension. You set it in the `download` attribute.

Comment: then why type: 'application/json' works fine?

Comment: Because Chrome think they are smart... You should not rely on this behavior. It is not per specs and I would personally even consider it a bug. Always set the filename with the extension yourself in the download attribute.

Comment: ok,i will take your advise,thanks!